# Read JSON Value in Javascript upto multiple levels

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angular-material

I Have a array of JSON Objects as follows:

```
columns: [{
    id: 'id',
    header: 'Employee ID',
    value: 'id'
  },
  {
    id: 'name',
    header: 'Employee Name',
    value: 'name'
  },
  {
    id: 'address',
    header: 'Employee address',
    value: 'info.address'
  },
]
```

In the HTML file, I loop through the array as follows:

```
    <ng-container *ngFor="let eachCol of columns" matColumnDef="{{eachCol.id}}">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{eachCol.header}}</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
         {{ row[eachCol.value] }}
      </td>
    </ng-container>
```

This works for JSON value upto level 1, i.e it works for id and name. I get employee id and employee name correctly. I get empty output for "info.address". "info.address" is being read as a string.

Comment: You cannot access properties of your address info.address like. What you have done is equivalent to row["info.address"], which instead of hierarchical search looks for the property info.address directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could make a directive or function that does what you want:

```
function pathToValue(obj, path) {
    const parts = path.split(".");
    let currentValue = obj;

    for(let i=0; i<parts.length; i++) {
        if (currentValue.hasOwnProperty(parts[i])) {
            currentValue = currentValue[parts[i]];
        }
    }

    return currentValue;
}
```

And use it in your template:

```
{{ pathToValue(row, eachCol.value) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please mention your element like:

```
{
    id: 'info.address',
    header: 'Employee address',
    value: 'info.address'
  }
```

or :

```
{
    id: 'address',
    header: 'Employee address',
    value: 'address'
  }
```

as per your logic valie and id should be same to locate header.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest your json like(*)

```
columns: [{
    id: 'id',
    header: 'Employee ID',
    value: ['id']
  },
  {
    id: 'name',
    header: 'Employee Name',
    value: ['name']
  },
  {
    id: 'address',
    header: 'Employee address',
    value: ['info','address']
  },
]
```

And

```
{{eachCol.value.length==1?
     row[eachCol.value[0]]:
     row[eachCol.value[0]][eachCol.value[1]]}}
```

(*) you can get it only using

```
   this.columns.forEach(x=>{
      x.value=x.value.split('.')
   })
```

Comment: Suppose I have a JSON with multiple levels, {
    id: 'address',
    header: 'Employee address',
    value: ['info','address', 'street', ...]
  }, Is there a way I can loop over the array?

Comment: Then, take a look Tim's answer -or another function similar-, in .html interpolation you can use a small numbers of operators. Perhaps creating a custom pipe.